# Checking data from a text file

Tags: python, passwords, readlines, file-writing

I've been trying to create a program that takes an input and checks to see whether that input is in some text from a file. My end goal is to create a user login GUI, but I will not show the code for the GUI here as there is quite a lot. 
I need to work out how to compare text from an input and from the file.
This is my code so far

```
def check(entry):
    search = open('password.txt', 'r')
    if str(entry) in str(search): 
        return (entry, "Word found")
    else:
        return entry, ("Word not found")

with open('password.txt', 'r') as text:
    print (text.read())

while True:
    entry=input("\nSearch for word: ")
    print(check(entry))
```

When I run the code it will say that 1, 2, 5 and 12 are all in the text but none of the words that are in text are confirmed.
If anyone could help it would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would suggest loading your file into a dictionary at the start of your application and compare against that. Performing a lot of file IO operations can be a drain on your application performance. Also, you should never be storing plain text passwords. It is a major security concern.

Comment: yes thatw will be something that i will move on to create, but at the current moment, I just want to get the login actually working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the security bad ideas covered in another comment, str(search) doesn't work like you think it does. If you print it, you should see something like:

```
<open file 'password.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0000000001EB2810>
```

which is a description of the object you created with the open function. You need to read the file into a string first with the .read() method.

Comment: okay, that makes more sense, compared to what I though. so I would use for str(entry) in str(search.read()):